# Make two linear cURL requests over TOR with same IP

Tags: php, http, curl, tor, http-pipelining

Before response my question - be awared that's not related to the following subjects:

[cURL: two seperate requests, same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753224/curl-two-seperate-requests-same-session)

[select outgoing ip for curl request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425651/select-outgoing-ip-for-curl-request)

[PHP Multiple Curl Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900153/php-multiple-curl-requests)

I'm working in a anti-captcha system and one of another validations it's the same IP can't do 5 requests per/hour, and because that I'm using TOR. But I need follow this sequence/flow:

1. Access startup URL (`Example: http://server/start-session`) - get captcha and set a cookie with the verify token
2. Submit captcha chars (`Example: http://server/verify-captcha`), with token, session id and I must keep IP from the startup URL

Using TOR after each request I have a new IP and there is a server side validation that's sets my IP when the session was started, in another words, if my IP changes the session is considered invalid even though I send the session id and correct token with valid captcha chars.

How can I keep the my IP with TOR for 2 consecutives requests?

Comment: You don't have a public IP with TOR: https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en

Comment: @AlexW thats the point. HTTP 1.1 suports pipelining, but how can implements that with cURL and TOR?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your TOR configuration. By default it only switches IP each 10 minutes. I suggest you refer in here for details: [How to change tor exit node programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969958/how-to-change-tor-exit-node-in-a-program-way)